# delete 0 and restack in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this issue in excel where I want to delete 0 and re-stack the rows.

Problem:

```
0 0 1 2 3
0 0 0 1 0
0 2 3 0 1
2 5 3 0 0
```

The desired result would be

```
1 2 3
1 0
2 3 0 1
2 5 3 0 0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are each of those in separate cells?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a range from the first non `0` to the end and then the outer INDEX will return them in order as it is dragged across.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX($A1:$E1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN($A1:$E1)/($A1:$E1<>0),1)):$E1,,COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of giving alternatives:

[image]

Formula in `A6` translates to:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A1:$E1,,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($A1:$E1>0,0),0)+COLUMN()-1),"")
```

Dragged down and sideways.

Comment: This is an array formula just with out the Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  The `INDEX($A1:$E1>0,0)` is a native array formula just like AGGREGATE.

Comment: but it is shorter and saves typing.

Comment: Thank you Scott for the information. I have made that mistake before than :S. Either way, this was a fun little puzzle.